# Редактирование встроенного шаблона в Elementor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, elementor

Установил плагин Elementor (плагин для wordpress) и пытался найти вставку необходимого элемента после определенного элемента (а именно после логотипа digitalelectronics), но не обнаружил нужного пункта меню интерфейса Elementor

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете просто потянуть нужный элемент под логотип и всё, да тут всё просто. Или если Вы меня не поняли, нажмите на кнопку(указал в приложении) и вставьте элемент туда под логотип. Надеюсь, объяснил понятно. [image: Приложение]