# header.php и прочее

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, header

Поскольку ответа на вопрос [Редактирование встроенного шаблона в Elementor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1176246/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2-elementor)

я не получил, спрашиваю: какие файлы мне необходимо редактировать, чтобы изменить шапку сайта в `wordpress`, кроме `header.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Шаблоны в Wordpress собираются из разных модулей, плагинов, функций тем и другого кода.

Разобраться, что именно формирует конечный вид шапки, можно только полностью разобравшись в коде header.php - там могут быть функции, выводящие разные части шаблоны, такие как логотип, виджеты, меню и прочее. Для каждого шаблона этот код будет разным, многие темы используют свои уникальные функции со своим поведением.

Если вы хотите изменить какую-то тему под свои требования, но не знаете как это сделать, вы можете обратиться к автору темы или к опытным разработчикам WP.